# how to fix google oauth authorization request response 400 (Oauth error) !! 1

Tags: authorization, google-oauth

> I have requested on https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth to get authorization code but only get 400 Oauth error !! 1. 
>   **Can you give request format and params so that I can get where am i getting wrong ?**

```
Here is request :
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?scope=https://mail.google.com/&redirect_uri=https://www.msn.com&access_type=offline&client_id=*********.apps.googleusercontent.com&response_type=code&include_granted_scopes=true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do realize that this is only the consent url you are using.  There will be additional calls after this.

This is the link I use to request the consent form from the user. You will only need to change the redirect uri for yours.  Remember the response will be returned to the redirect uri in that instance.

> Get https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id={clientid}.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly&response_type=code

Code ripped from [Google 3 Legged OAuth2 Flow](https://www.daimto.com/google-3-legged-oauth2-flow/)

Comment: @DalmTo for testing pupose on local postman what can I specify as a redirect_url?

Comment: for postman you have to set that up because postman has its own redirect uri I think.